# How to build a simple app that turns text to m4a files

Tags: mac, terminal, text-to-speech, m4a

I'm learning Chinese and want a way to quickly generate and save words and phrases to m4a files.

I've managed to do pretty much what I want in terminal, but I can't seem to figure out how to make an app out of it. Here is the code I've used in terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/test
say -o "whateveriwantittosay.m4a" "whateveriwantittosay"
```

How do I make an shell or Apple script that when opened prompts me for whateveriwantittosay, then creates the file? And maybe even asks me again for a new file.

Thanks!

Comment: If you add a function like `cnsay() { for a; do say "$a" -o ~/"Desktop/$a.m4a"; done; }` to `~/.bash_profile`, you could run it with something like `cnsay word1 word2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Automator Application :

- Create a new Application
- Add a **Ask for text** action
- Add a **Run a sheel script** action
- Select **Pass input as Arguments**
- Copy the following script (Assuming ~/Desktop/Test exists)

=>

```
cd ~/Desktop/Test
say -o "$@.m4a" $@
```

- Save your application. It's ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

i would use python for this... since it is included in the vanilla OSX distibution.

Check [wxPython](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/Phoenix/index.html) together with [pyApp](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/Phoenix/PyApp.html)
assuming you mean a gui-based app..

Using python you can use subprocess in order to call any terminal command from python eg:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("date")
```

Comment: As written this does not really answer the question. Can you provide a sample python script which accomplishes what the asker is looking for in the question?

Comment: Question was edited since i answered to specify a shell or applescript.

Comment: Python is ok as well